# Error when printing Qweb quotation [Odoo9]

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, qwebview, qweb

When I try to print a quotation, I have the following error. I didn't edit any of the files mentioned in the error. I have create a new module and inherited the default template of quotation. When I click on "print" I have the error message.
It seems to be an error in the python code, but I didn't edit any line of Python.

```
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/report/controllers/main.py", line 96, in report_download
    response = self.report_routes(reportname, docids=docids, converter='pdf')
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 509, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/report/controllers/main.py", line 45, in report_routes
    pdf = report_obj.get_pdf(cr, uid, docids, reportname, data=data, context=context)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/report/models/report.py", line 157, in get_pdf
    html = self.get_html(cr, uid, ids, report_name, data=data, context=context)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/report/models/report.py", line 131, in get_html
    return self.render(cr, uid, [], report.report_name, docargs, context=context)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/report/models/report.py", line 107, in render
    return view_obj.render(cr, uid, template, values, context=context)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web_editor/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 29, in render
    return super(view, self).render(cr, uid, id_or_xml_id, values=values, engine=engine, context=context)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 1072, in render
    return self.pool[engine].render(cr, uid, id_or_xml_id, qcontext, loader=loader, context=context)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 254, in render
    return self.render_node(element, qwebcontext, generated_attributes=qwebcontext.pop('generated_attributes', ''))
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 297, in render_node
    result = self.render_element(element, template_attributes, generated_attributes, qwebcontext)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 320, in render_element
    generated_attributes= name == "t" and generated_attributes or ''))
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 295, in render_node
    result = self._render_tag[t_render](self, element, template_attributes, generated_attributes, qwebcontext)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 448, in render_tag_call
    d[0] = self.render_element(element, template_attributes, generated_attributes, d)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 320, in render_element
    generated_attributes= name == "t" and generated_attributes or ''))
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 295, in render_node
    result = self._render_tag[t_render](self, element, template_attributes, generated_attributes, qwebcontext)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 426, in render_tag_foreach
    ru.append(self.render_element(element, template_attributes, generated_attributes, copy_qwebcontext))
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 320, in render_element
    generated_attributes= name == "t" and generated_attributes or ''))
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 295, in render_node
    result = self._render_tag[t_render](self, element, template_attributes, generated_attributes, qwebcontext)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 459, in render_tag_call
    res = self.render(cr, uid, template, d)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 254, in render
    return self.render_node(element, qwebcontext, generated_attributes=qwebcontext.pop('generated_attributes', ''))
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 297, in render_node
    result = self.render_element(element, template_attributes, generated_attributes, qwebcontext)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 320, in render_element
    generated_attributes= name == "t" and generated_attributes or ''))
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 295, in render_node
    result = self._render_tag[t_render](self, element, template_attributes, generated_attributes, qwebcontext)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 448, in render_tag_call
    d[0] = self.render_element(element, template_attributes, generated_attributes, d)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 320, in render_element
    generated_attributes= name == "t" and generated_attributes or ''))
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 297, in render_node
    result = self.render_element(element, template_attributes, generated_attributes, qwebcontext)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 320, in render_element
    generated_attributes= name == "t" and generated_attributes or ''))
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 297, in render_node
    result = self.render_element(element, template_attributes, generated_attributes, qwebcontext)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 320, in render_element
    generated_attributes= name == "t" and generated_attributes or ''))
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 297, in render_node
    result = self.render_element(element, template_attributes, generated_attributes, qwebcontext)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 320, in render_element
    generated_attributes= name == "t" and generated_attributes or ''))
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 297, in render_node
    result = self.render_element(element, template_attributes, generated_attributes, qwebcontext)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 320, in render_element
    generated_attributes= name == "t" and generated_attributes or ''))
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 297, in render_node
    result = self.render_element(element, template_attributes, generated_attributes, qwebcontext)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 325, in render_element
    raise_qweb_exception(message="Could not render element %r" % element.tag, node=element, template=template)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 320, in render_element
    generated_attributes= name == "t" and generated_attributes or ''))
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 295, in render_node
    result = self._render_tag[t_render](self, element, template_attributes, generated_attributes, qwebcontext)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 505, in render_tag_field
    options = json.loads(foptions)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
QWebException: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 88 (char 87)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to restart your server ? sometimes it works. You could also update the database.